# ZFS nfsshare to export RW and RO host?

Tags: solaris, nfs, zfs, opensolaris

I have been exporting NFS from OpenSloarins like this (successfully):

```
zfs set sharenfs=root=rw=host1:host2:host3 pool1
```

I'm acting according the man pages `sharefs`, `share_nfs` but the following does not work:

```
zfs set sharenfs=root=rw=host1:host2:host3,ro=host4 pool1
```

All hosts loose access permission.

How can I share to some hosts as read/write and to some as read only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a syntax problem. The value of the sharenfs property is the options that get sent to `share(1)`. Try

```
zfs set sharenfs=rw=host1:host2:host3,ro=host4 pool1
```

unless you really do need to be exporting the filesystems with root permissions to all those hosts, in which case it's safest to be explicit:

```
zfs set sharenfs=rw=host1:host2:host3,root=host1:host2:host3,ro=host4 pool1
```

(or better yet, use a netgroup or network instead).

Comment: Yes. This was wrong `sharenfs=root=rw=`. Your config is now in my production.